# linux shell script to run an executable file in current folder

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have an executable file always in */home/a* called **toUpperCase**.

Now I am in the folder */home/bla/blabla/b* where I have a text file to be converted to uppercase (*toConvert.txt*).
All I want to do is a script that executed in */home/bla/blabla/b* does something like

```
#!/bin/bash
./"/home/a/toUpperCase" toConvert.txt
```

So in the end I should have **converted.txt** in the folder */home/bla/blabla/b*

But it gives me an error like `line 2: .//home/a/toUpperCase: does not exist`

How can I resolve this problem? thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
"/home/a/toUpperCase" toConvert.txt
```